# Autofill from a named range to a unnamed destination in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to autofill from a named range to its right neighbour cells. The original range contains combined cells and is `4x4` cells in size. My problem is that the `Autofill`-method needs a `Destination:=Range("...")` and does not take something like `Destination:=xlSameAreaToTheRight`.

The solution would be if I could do something like

```
Range("origin").AutoFill Destination:=( Range("origin").Area + Rows(4) ), _
                         Type:=xlFillDefault
```

So how can I find the rows and cols of a named range in the format `A1:D4` and add like 4 cols to it?

Thnks for your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to get as result, but here are the answers to your particular questions:

You can get the Range as String in the format $A$1:$D$4 using `.Address`, and to get the amount ofthe columns just add `.Columns.Count` to the named range. (Using offset is should be no problem to add the amount of the columns to the active cell within your range.)

```
Dim TestRange As String
Dim AmountColumns As Integer

TestRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("Test").Address
AmountColumns = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("Test").Columns.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [stema](https://stackoverflow.com/users/626273/stema)'s answer I found a (quite simple) solution:

To add rows or cols to a named range and use it as AutoFill destination one can simply do

```
Range("origin").AutoFill Destination:=( Range("origin").Range("A1:H2") ), _
                         Type:=xlFillDefault
```

what would autofill four columns and two rows to our "origin":

```
|       1       |       2       |
|  1,1  |  1,2  |  2,1  |  2,2  |
```

This leads to:

```
|       1       |       2       |       3       |       4       |
|  1,1  |  1,2  |  2,1  |  2,2  |  2,7  |  3,12 |  3,54 |  3,96 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to use @stema's suggestion.

```
Sub namedfill()

    Dim locOrig As String
    Dim firstCell As String
    Dim lastCell As String

    'Pluck address of top-left and bottom-right cells from .Address string
    locOrig = Range("Origin").Address
    firstCell = Left(locOrig, 4)
    lastCell = Right(locOrig, 4)

    Range("Origin").AutoFill Destination:=Range(firstCell, Range(lastCell).Offset(0, 4)), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```